# Android : Image uploaded to server is always 0 bytes

Tags: php, android, image, bitmap

I am trying to upload (post) a form data - along with an image to the server. I have tried the following code but unable to pinpoint the error.

**Android Code :**

I am creating an object of class Product in the main activity and sending it to the background activity. Where I am trying to upload the data to the server.

Steps Used :

1. Browsed image from gallery and displayed in image view.
2. On click even of "Upload" button in main activity converted the
   image to bitmap and set it inside an object of class Product
3. Started a background activity and passed the product reference
   created in Step 2
4. Fetch the Bitmap from the product object, covert it into byte
   array.. and then convert in to String using Base64.
5. Post the data to the server.

```
protected String doInBackground(Products... params) {
    Products pd=params[0];
    Bitmap bmp=pd.getImage();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Log.e("Bitmap ","height : "+bmp.getHeight()+" Width :"+bmp.getWidth());
    Log.e("Size of bmp",""+bmp.getByteCount());
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bos);
    Log.e("Size of bos",""+bos.size());
    byte[] imageToByte = bos.toByteArray();
    String imageData = Base64.encodeToString(imageToByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.e("Base64 encoded image",imageData);

    Log.e("Status","Image Parsed");

    try{
        String link="*****/sellPage.php";

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("uploadedimage", "UTF-8") + "=" + imageData;
        Log.e("Image Data",data);
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        Log.e("Status", "Request Sent");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        Log.e("Status","Response forwarded for processing");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

**PHP Code to read the data from android and write to a file**

```
$imgsrc = base64_decode($_POST['uploadedimage']); 

echo $imsrc;

$fp = fopen('myImage1.jpg', 'w');

fwrite($fp, $imgsrc);

if(fclose($fp)){ echo "Successful";}

else{ echo "Error uploading image";}
```

**Output**

The file is being created at the server but the size of the file is 0 bytes only. Once or twice the file was of few hundred KB's but there was no output when I tried to display it in the "img" tag.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: don't treat "files" as POST. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for the quick response. So should I send the file as MultipartEntity and then save it at the server end using $_FILES ?

Comment: you're welcome. exactly.

Comment: You are making a normal `GET` request with `uploadimage` as key and `imageData` as value. So, fetch it from `$_GET[]` instead of `$_POST[]`.

Comment: and that too ^ files require POST

Comment: Ok Thanks.

Although I am able to send the data to the server using the above method and nor I am using $HTTP_POST_FILES. And I found the above code in a few tutorials and in some posts here on StackOverFlow as well. So was not able to figure out my mistake.

Mean while I will try the other way as well :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: But, OP is sending the file as a string appending it to the URL, so I am not sure, POST is required. (Correct me if I am wrong!)

Comment: @PrerakSola you're not wrong. Files require POST. I don't know Android though, so I can't help there.

Comment: I also created the a Registration module (no images) before this... and used similar code and there I am fetching with $_POST only and that is working fine.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the update @Fred-ii- .... :)

Comment: you're welcome @PrerakSola

Comment: so try `$_FILES['uploadedimage']` instead of `$_POST['uploadedimage']` but I won't be able to help with the Android stuff though. @HarshBafna Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii  :  Yes I am trying that method (MultipartEntity)... Will need to change the code... currently I am sending the image data as string (Base 64 encoded) and not as file so $_FILES won't work with this code. I just wanted to know the mistakes in this approach.

Comment: @HarshBafna: For the android side, if you are in a learning phase, give a shot to OkHTTP library for making requests to the server. It will reduce the complexity and the code. You can find the details over here: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: @Prerak Sola : Thanks. I will give it a shot too.  :-)

Comment: @HarshBafna did you solve your problem? I have a similar problem. About 10 % of the images I uploaded with my android app are 0 KB on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code with your code for sending image to the back end

```
mEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    if (byteArray != null || bitmap != null) {
     mEntity.addPart("profile_pic", new ByteArrayBody(byteArray,
       "image/jpg", "" + etName.getText().toString()
       + "_profile_pic.jpg"));
```

and for the back end side you can get the image as `$_FILES['profile_pic']` .you will get the image and with all the details related with image.